# Convert EF-based app to multi-tenant by way of context overrides

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework, code-first based app that I have to make multi-tenant, which is to say that there are about a half-dozen "top level" entities that now need to reference the specific tenant ID. (As we get to 100's of users, no, we're not going to maintain individual schema, so please don't suggest that. :))

With an object-oriented abstraction over the data access like EF, I'm trying to imagine how I can get to a place where I don't need to change any of the underlying code outside of the dbcontext to make this work. Essentially, I want to use these as my success criteria:

- Existing data access code doesn't have to be changed. There's a ton of it, lots of it is procedural and duplicate. No repository classes, unfortunately, and as much as I want to get there, it's technical debt I have to defer.
- Queries filter those top-level objects on the tenant ID. So for example, existing code gets context.Members.Where(x => x.IsAwesome) but magically also filters to where tenant ID equals tenant ID (the tenant context is available per request and available for injection).
- Adding top-level entities also assigns the tenant ID. In other words, the code does something like context.Members.Add(newEntity) and newEntity magically gets its TenantID property set to that ID available via that injected component.

It seems like setting the tenant ID could be done with the entity class itself (haven't thought through the injection on that, some kind of shim stuck in there), but I'm not sure how best to go about adding an additional filter for querying.

Comment: How do I achieve the success criteria? See also last sentence.

Comment: So you want to leave existing code completely untouched (except context code)?

Comment: That's the ideal world, yes. Not averse to modifying the entity types themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure it can be done completely without code changes, but here's how I would approach this. First, introduce an interface for your multi-tenant entities (I assume each of them has `TenantID` property, mapped to database column):

```
public interface IMultiTenantEntity {
    int TenantID { get; set; }
}
```

Then implement it for all your entities. They are autogenerated, but partial, so just do:

```
public partial class YourEntity : IMultiTenantEntity {}
```

Now, to fill this property on saving, override `SaveChanges` in your context (again, it's autogenerated, but partial, so you don't have to touch autogenerated code):

```
public partial class YourContext : DbContext
{
    private int _tenantId;
    public override int SaveChanges() {
        var addedEntities = this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(c => c.State == EntityState.Added)
            .Select(c => c.Entity).OfType<IMultiTenantEntity>();

        foreach (var entity in addedEntities) {
            entity.TenantID = _tenantId;
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IQueryable<Code> TenantCodes => this.Codes.Where(c => c.TenantID == _tenantId);
}
```

Above I assume you already injected current tenant id into `_tenantId` field somehow.

Then, for each entity set, add separate property which will return this set filtered by `TenantID` (again in partial class for your context):

```
public IQueryable<YourEntity> TenantYourEntities => this.YourEntities.Where(c => c.TenantID == _tenantId);
```

Now all you need to do is find all references to the sets of `YourEntities` (with right-click > find all references) and replace them with references to `TenantYourEntities`. Then all your queries will be filtered by `TenantID` without much work. Of course, don't replace references where you use DbSet to modify entities (`Db.YourEntities.Add(...)`).

Comment: That's awesome... I'm going to give this a whirl and see what happens. Will follow up, but while the DbSet part is a little inconvenient to refactor, I suspect this is the best way. I was hung up on the save part because I wasn't super clear on how the state tracking was set up.

Comment: Alternatively you can modify .tt file of your context so that it generates your DbSets with names like "AllMembers", while for Members properties it generates those tenant-filtered queries. Then all your existing queries (context.Members....) will become filtered by tenant. But all your context.Members.Add(...) statements will now produce compile-time error, which might be easier to fix.

Comment: Just a follow-up... an interesting problem is that if you declare an index in context model builder that includes the parent TenantEntity's ID, the save method appears to treat the property as "new" and therefore doesn't persist it. It's pretty weird.

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically, as long as the tenant ID is known at the time of the context instantiation, you can simply set a field on your context with that value, and reference that field in your overloads. For example, you could do something like read it from Application Settings. Right-click on your project and choose "Properties". Then, go to the "Settings" tab, and turn it on. Put in whatever you will use in development there. Then, add configurations to your project for each tenant, and edit the config transforms to switch it out the appropriate value. In your DI initialization, then, you can read this setting value and inject it as a constant.

If the tenant is being set at runtime, such as via part of the URL, then using DI becomes a bit more difficult. The context will generally be request-scoped, so that's not really a problem. However, the DI initialization is *usually* not done within the request pipeline. At that point, you'd probably just need to set the value manually, or otherwise create your context within code that *is* part of the request pipeline, such as the controller.

Comment: But the question is not how to inject id (I think), but how to automatically set that in Where clause, and automatically set that to related entities before saving them to database.

Comment: Yes, what @Evk said. I'm not super worried about injecting context. If I have to use a concrete instance of the tenant context shim, that's not a big deal. The app is already tightly coupled, so I have bigger issues there. :) But yeah, see success criteria and the last sentence in the question text.