# Entity framework add where clause to all queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a project that is using Entity framework and AspNet Identity.

One of the parameters of the IdentityUser is a deactivated field.

Within the app, if I wanted to get the users, I would do this:

```
var users = Context.Users //etc....
```

However, I do not want this query to return any deactivated users. I know I could do this

```
var users = Context.Users.Where(x => x.Deactivated != true);
```

However, I am reluctant to do this, as I am sure that in time someone will forget to add this where clause.

Is there a way for entity to do this automatically to all context queries? I have found this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters

But I do not have EF core and cannot upgrade to it.

I know I could make a wrapper function and call this, but I am trying to find a better solution...

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this for _all_ context queries?  e.g. How would you re-activate a user?

Comment: @RikRak I can access these users via role requests

Comment: Maybe https://www.agile-code.com/blog/entity-framework-code-first-applying-global-filters/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698793/how-can-i-automatically-filter-out-soft-deleted-entities-with-entity-framework?fireglass_rsn=true#fireglass_params|&tabid=af13892376ccfce3&application_server_address=fg-vb2.dmz.local&popup=true&is_right_side_popup=false&start_with_session_counter=1

Comment: You can also check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441204/multitenancy-with-dbcontext-and-tenantid-interceptors-filters-ef-code-first

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I often use a combination of `XXXStore` members and `XXX` members where the `XXXStore` is the `DBSet` and the `XXX` is a query with `AsNoTracking()`. I then use the `XXX` members in queries responding to `GET`s and the `XXXStore` only when I want to update the database. E.g.

```
    public DbSet<User> UserStore { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<User> Users => UserStore.AsNoTracking();
```

This gives the advantage of not tracking entities that won't be updated, but with a DRY approach that means not adding the `AsNoTracking()` verbosely all over the place.

This approach can easily be combined with a `where` clause:

```
    public DbSet<User> UserStore { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<User> Users => UserStore.AsNoTracking().Where(u => !u.Deactivated);
```

Filters can also work, but an advantage to this approach is that it's easy to make an exception when you really do need to access a deactivated user, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Global Filters:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder){
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().Property<string>("TenantId").HasField("_tenantId");
    // Configure entity filters
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasQueryFilter(b => EF.Property<string>(b, "TenantId") == _tenantId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsDeleted);
}
```

Comment: Where do you get _tenantId?

Comment: just an example, it can be much simpler : modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsDeleted);  assuming that isDeleted is a field